# How Drop function Works?

Tags: rust

my code down there do not work!
i read a Rust book.i read if you want to drop a value you can write drop(name);

```
fn main() {
    let n = 1;
    std::mem::drop(n);
    println!("{}", n);
}
```

it run on my terminal, but why does not `n` dropped?

Answer (score 6):

Rust has an awesome documentation, check it out for [`std::mem::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html). Some info from this web-page I linked:

```
pub fn drop<T>(_x: T)
```

> Disposes of a value.
>
> This does so by calling the argument’s implementation of Drop.
>
> This effectively does nothing for types which implement Copy, e.g. integers. Such values are copied and then moved into the function, so the value persists after this function call.
>
> This function is not magic; it is literally defined as
>
> ```
> pub fn drop<T>(_x: T) { }
> ```
>
> Because _x is moved into the function, it is automatically dropped before the function returns.

Comment: That is all a good explanation, but I feel as though it misses the main point of his question: "Why is `n` not dropped", which is because `n` is a `Copy` type.

Comment: @jeremymeadows Given that `n` is an integer, I think this is pretty obvious.

Answer (score -1):

In your example, `n` is an integer type. Integers are not allocated in heap memory, so there isn't a memory reference to drop, and thus the call doesn't need to do anything.

In the docs for [`std::mem::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html), it explains that "Integers and other types implementing `Copy` are unaffected by `drop`."

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether the type is an integer or even manages any heap allocations, it has to do with a type implementing `Copy` or not. You can create a user-defined struct that doesn't implement `Copy` and owns no heap allocations, and `std::mem::drop()` will still render it unusable.

Comment: Huh? I'm only basing the integer statement off of the example which OP posted. I guess `Copy` and heap allocations aren't necessarily mutually exclusive (although pretty much every Rust reference implies that they *should* be). I do specify that it is all because of the `Copy` trait, and site it.

Comment: The problem is this sentence: _"Integers are not allocated in heap memory, so there isn't a memory reference to drop, and thus the call doesn't need to do anything."_ The question is why `n` is still usable after the call to `drop()` and this makes it sound very much like you're saying that types that don't manage a heap allocation or don't have a destructor are no-ops for `drop()` when that's not entirely true.